# Share book uploaded to my Google Play Books account with other account

Tags: ebook-management, google-play-books

I uploaded a book to my Google Play Books account and I want to share it with another account, is that possible?
I know that I can give it the .epub file but I deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you uploaded that specific book to google play books (in contrast to buying it on that platform) you can simply download it as a epub/pdf file using Adobe Digital Editions.
A detailed tutorial on this procedure can be found at [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/179863?hl=en).

Comment: Can't you just download it directly from the site like you do with purchased books and then he could email the book to the other account and they could upload it on there end?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I suppose that I will have to do that of download it and upload in the other account